# Declaring a context method with this

Tags: android, android-context

How would I declare this method if I wanted to do it in an `onClick` method:

```
public void addBook(Context context) {
```

Would it be `addBook(context);`?

I'm having trouble implementing it. I think it keeps causing my activity to force a close because I'm typing it wrong:

```
public class book_edit extends Activity {

public String book_name;
public String isbn;
public String author;
public float ratings;
public EditText title;
public EditText book_author;
public EditText isbn_number;
public EditText name;
public RatingBar ratingbar;
public Button save;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_book_list);

    title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    book_author = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.author);
    isbn_number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isbn);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }
    });

    final RatingBar ratingbar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,      boolean fromUser) {

            ratingbar.setRating(rating);

        }
    });

    }

public void addBook(Context context) {
String tag = "Excersising BookProvider";
Log.d(tag, "adding a book");

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_NAME, book_name);

cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_ISBN, isbn);

cv.put(BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.BOOK_AUTHOR, author);

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Uri uri    =  BookProviderMetaData.BookTableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;

Log.d(tag, "book insert uri: " +uri);

Uri insertedUri = cr.insert(uri, cv);

Log.d(tag, "inserted    uri:" + insertedUri);

   }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

onClick method goes with View parameter

```
onClick(View view);
```

You allways can call view.getContext() to obtain context instanse for your addBook

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
        addBook(view.getContext());
     }     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `book_edit.this` as a parameter for your method, that should work.

Comment: It keeps for closing and this is the error i get.                  07-01 14:43:54.780: ERROR/ActivityThread(622): Failed to find provider info for  + AUTHORITY +